# What goes in the request body for an HTTP POST request using the YouTube API?

Tags: excel, vba, api, http, youtube

I found an answer on how to do an HTTP POST request, I just don't know how to put the YouTube API syntax with it. Here's the sub for the POST request:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send("")]
```

Now here is the syntax for a playlistitems.insert YouTube API POST request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN] Accept: application/json Content-Type: application/json
{ "snippet": { "playlistId": "PLO0tYa-h6I_9xJlanhquO8F-rZe6sA0kd", "position": 0, "resourceId": { "kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10" } } }
```

[Error and VBA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khHgO.png)

[Sheet for VBA code reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Nc2.png)

[Example from Google Developer that works. I just need to do this in Excel VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBzX8.png)

I have the auth key, the videoid, and playlistid so how do I put this in the request body for an Excel VBA HTTP POST request?

Comment: set the headers as provided by YouTube. Then pass the JSON string in the `.Send` command.

Comment: So the header is the POST https part and the JSON string is the { "snippet" part?

Comment: Headers are "Authorization", "Content-Type", etc. and yes on the JSON string.

Comment: I get error 450 wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I added pics for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim json as String
    json = "{""snippet"":{""playlistId"":""PLO0tYa-h6I_9xJlanhquO8F-rZe6sA0kd"",""position"":0,""resourceId"":{""kind"":""youtube#video"",""videoId"": ""M7FIvfx5J10""}}}"

    Dim URL as String

    URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]"

    Dim objHTTP as Object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    With objHTTP

        .Open "POST", URL, False
        'don't think this is needed
        '.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
         .setRequestHeader "Authorization","Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]"
         .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
         .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
         .send json

         Do: DoEvents: Loop Until: .readyStatus = 4 'check my syntax here, i may have mis-remembered exact method names.

         Dim x as String
         x = .responsetext

   End WIth

   debug.print x
```